# Go to cell edit mode and select all cell text with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am wrote a macro that checks for changes to certain cells.  If the new value in a cell doesn't meet certain criteria, it enters the cell in edit mode and selects all text in that cell using keyboard shortcuts:

```
Application.SendKeys ("{HOME}+{END}")
```

This always enters edit mode, but often fails to select the text.  I'm looking for something more reliable.  Any ideas?

Here's the entire macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' -------------------------------
' Only run the macro if a single cell is selected
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

' -------------------------------
' Declare variables
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim AccountToFind As String

' -------------------------------
' Assign values to shared variables
    AccountToFind = Target.Value

' -------------------------------
' Validate change in HEADER, column D
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then

        For Each cell In Sheets("_coding references").Range("AccountsPayable[NAME]")
            If cell.Value = AccountToFind Then Exit Sub  ' passed validation
        Next cell

        Target.Select

        MsgBox ("'" & AccountToFind & "'" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is not a listed A/P account!")

' --------------------------------------------------------------
' --------------------------------------------------------------
' HERE'S THE PROBLEMATIC CODE
' --------------------------------------------------------------
            Application.SendKeys ("{F2}{HOME}+{END}")
' --------------------------------------------------------------
' --------------------------------------------------------------
' --------------------------------------------------------------
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to catch this event. Your only way to go is "sending keys," and since all of them have to be pressed at the same time, this is the best workaround -to my knowledge- that you can do: either use [sleep or wait](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/) function.

```
Application.SendKeys ("{F2}{HOME}")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.SendKeys ("+{END}")
```

***Explanation***

 Sending keys relies on the processor speed, so it will always be variable. Even if the code is well written, you have to consider some time to let it "press" -virtually- all the keys at the same time.

Comment: It sort of works however if NumLock is not set then F2 does not work :) Also F2 messes up NumLock... IT IS HORRIBLE.... https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-sendkeys-f2-and-numlock-issue.922779/